# Fixed Element scrolling within parallax element

Tags: html, css

I'm running into an issue where a fixed element (The nav) moves when the body element is used as a parallax container with the following css:

```
.parallax {
    perspective: 1px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Where the original body element has this css:

```
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -1.4rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

And the original nav has this css:

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0rem;
    right: 0rem;
    height: 100%;
    /*animation*/
    transition-timing-function: all ease 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s; /* Safari */
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
```

Where the fixed position style only breaks when the parallax class is applied to the body element.

All of this is within this representation of the html:

```
<body class="parallax">
    <header></header>
    <div></div>
    <nav></nav>
</body>
```

Why did it break?

Edit to clarify some confusion: no javascript is involved, the parallax container class is shown above, nothing else has been added. Upon inspection, the nav element still has the fixed position style applied to it

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hq3bp9y/)

*(As an aside, I know the work-around is to add parallax to a different container instead, and have the nav outside of that container, but in order to make sure iOS shrinks the url bar the body needs to be the element that scrolls)*

Comment: Well I'm not using any javascript here @cale_b, I'm trying to create the parallax only using css. I added an edit specifying the nav, and it is just a red square that moves when the body has the parallax class added to it.. The parallax class is shown in the first html. and the inspector shows the "fixed position" property as if it were normally applied

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith, I added a representation of the HTML, but its very simple... a fixed element within a container like i mentioned before.

Comment: Umm I don't see how the above code will give you anything close to a parallax scroll

Comment: This is an example of css only parallax https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw

Comment: I'm following this: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/ as well

Just wanted to isolate the issue here @AdamBuchananSmith

Comment: Create a fiddle for us then

Comment: Add a codepen/JSfiddle please

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith fiddle added at the end of the post!

Comment: Have you tried playing with it - what happens when you remove `perspective` from the parallax class? Does that fix it or is it still broken? What about if you remove `height`?  It would seem you could narrow it down fairly quickly with some simple debugging / testing.

Comment: What is the fiddle supposed to do? what should the red square do?

Comment: @cale_b, I'm just trying to learn why this is happening, if there is a technical explanation for it. It seems like perspective is the culprit here, but I don't know why

Comment: @cale_b just got the link you sent. That is exactly what i want to know! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to `perspective` being added via the `.parallax` class.

This cannot be overcome.

Any time you add transform (which is what perspective is) to an element, it becomes the positioning "base" for any positioned children, including `position: fixed`. Your position:fixed nav element becomes fixed *relative to the transformed parent*